# Tensorflow: How to use boolean_mask in a way that perserves 2D tensor shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I use tf.boolean_mask, the result is flattened.

```
tensor7 = tf.constant( [[ 0,  1,  2,  3, -1],[ 2,  3,  4, -1, -1],[ 3,  6,  5,  4,  3]], tf.int64)
mask7 = tf.constant([[ True,  True,  True,  True, False],  [ True,  True,  True, False, False], [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], tf.bool)
result7=tf.boolean_mask(tensor7, mask7, axis=0)  

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([ result7 ]))
```

> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 5, 4, 3])]

Is there a way to use it that preserves the original 3 array shape? The shapes of the individual arrays should change since they're shorter now. I'm looking for something like this

> [array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3 ],
>          [ 2,  3,  4 ],
>          [ 3,  6,  5,  4,  3]])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation may not be logically sound, as pointed out further [in this feature request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18238#issuecomment-378646160) that resembles your question. You would need to have dynamic shapes for tensors, which has only limited support in TensorFlow (e.g. [Ragged Tensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors)).

Comment: I tried with ragged tensors but that just raises another error. Dynamic shapes are possible for Tensors but just not ready for every function in Tensorflow. Marking as correct for this particular instance.